# Override new order email in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, email, email-templates

I have a custom module that needs to overwrite the new order email template, the location for the default email template is

**vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontendemail\order_new.html**,

and this file get the data from

**vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender.php**,

I need to override these two files from my custom module but I don't know how to do it

Comment: You can overrider email template using your custom theme Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html and block file using di.xml file

Comment: @Rakesh how to do it in custom module?

Comment: for email template i dont know how to override using custom module.

Comment: I found that the best way to do this is through an event observer.
More details in the accepted answer here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159142/override-model-function-magento-2

Comment: @David, were you able to change the sales order email template by overriding in custom module? If so then please share the code snippet, I need to do the same but unable to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Your override file path is incorrect.

You have to just override order_new.html file at below location.

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html
```

Clear & Flush the Cache by using below command:-

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite email templates in a module like this:

1. Create Vendor/Module/etc/email_templates.xml

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
       <template id="sales_email_order_template" label="Vendor New Order" file="sales/order_new.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
   </config>
   ```
2. Put your template in Vendor/Module/view/frontend/email/sales/order_new.html
3. Make sure that your module is loaded after original Magento_Sales module by adding dependency in Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

   ```xml
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="Vendor_Module">
           <sequence>
               <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
           </sequence>
       </module>
   </config>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Create the **order_new.html** file in your module, path:**app/code/{VendorName}/{PackageName}/view/frontend/email/**

**And do your customization.**