# Override model function Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, email-templates

I want to override one of the function in Magento core model which is located in

**vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class OrderSender
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class OrderSender extends Sender
{
  protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {
        $transport = [
            'order' => $order, 
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
        ];

        $transport = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($transport);

        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'email_order_set_template_vars_before',
            ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transport]
        );

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transport->getData());

        parent::prepareTemplate($order);
    }
}
```

I just want to add additional data to **$transport** array variable from my custom extension, but it seems not working because when I call the additional data it didn't print anything, here's what i've done:

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender"/>
</config>
```

**Namespace\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class OrderSender
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{


    public function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {

        $transport = [
            'order' => $order,
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'test' => '<p> Yoo Yeezy </p>',
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
        ];
        $transport = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($transport);

        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'email_order_set_template_vars_before',
            ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transport]
        );

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transport->getData());

        parent::prepareTemplate($order);
    }


}
```

Comment: have u put echo exit in ur override model function? seems ok http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

Comment: @AnkitShah i already did that, but it didnt echo anything, it goes straight to the core funtion

Comment: `module.xml` code `<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>` & then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: @AnkitShah when running setup:upgrade `[InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.`

Comment: Something wrong with ur module. Check log  for error http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103774/magento-2-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-on-windows

Comment: @AnkitShah it gives an erron when i add `</module> ` after my `<module ...>`

Comment: `module.xml` code `<?xml version="1.0" ?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>`

Comment: have you done this?

Comment: how can i change the template id? i want to send different email based on the shipping method selected, how can i implement it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on what kind of data you want to add, you might want to use an observer instead of rewriting the model:

`etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="add_extra_data_to_transport" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddExtraDataToTransport" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create `Observer\AddExtraDataToTransport.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddExtraDataToTransport implements ObserverInterface
{  
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        $transport['test'] = '<p> Yoo Yeezy </p>';
        if ($transport['payment_html'] == 'transfer') {
            $transport['payment_html'] = 'test';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i want change the data?

Comment: @simpleguy like change one of the original data in the `$transport` variable ?

Comment: yes, for example `if($transport['payment_html'] == 'transfer') $transport['payment_html'] = 'test';`

Comment: @simpleguy see my updated answer

Comment: when is use the `$order` variable , i got an error undefined variable

Comment: @simpleguy well that's normal there's no `$order` in my code

Comment: sorry my bad :D

Comment: $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport(); it's not getting in magento2.0.12 version.

Comment: In email template {{var test||raw}} is null. How i get the test value in email templates.

Comment: $transport is a Dataobject so you need to set data.

Answer (score 1):

Use an observer instead of rewriting the model:

`etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="add_extra_data_to_transport" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddExtraDataToTransport" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create Observer\AddExtraDataToTransport.php and change data

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddExtraDataToTransport implements ObserverInterface
{  
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        if ($transport->getPaymentHtml == 'transfer') {
            $transport->setPaymentHtml('test');
        }
    }
}
```

Checked at Magento 2.2.2

Comment: not working in Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of data you want to add, you might want to use an observer instead of rewriting the model:

Method to use custom variables in transactional Email in Magento 2:

1 - Create `registration.php` file in `app\code\[Vendor]\[Namespace]\`

```
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        '[Vendor]_[Namespace]',
          __DIR__
  );
```

2 - create `module.xml` file in `app\code\[Vendor]\[Namespace]\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="[Vendor]_[Namespace]" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
    </config>
```

3 - Create `events.xml` file in `app\code\[Vendor]\[Namespace]\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">    
                <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
            <observer name="add_extra_data_to_transport" instance="[Vendor]\[Namespace]\Observer\ObserverforAddCustomVariable" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

4 - Create `ObserverforAddCustomVariable.php` file in `app\code\[Vendor]\[Namespace]\Observer`

```
<?php

    namespace [Vendor]\[Namespace]\Observer;

    use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

    class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $customerRepository;
        public function __construct(
            CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
        ) {
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
            if($transport->getOrder() != null)
            {
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($transport->getOrder()->getCustomerId());
                if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('username')) {
                    $transport['username'] = $customer->getCustomAttribute('username')->getValue();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**You can use custom Email variable in email template like** “`{var username}`”