# Magento2 override sales email templates

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I'm going crazy. I've read a lot of tutorials and marked "as solved" topics on override template on sales email.
I'm trying to customize the sales_email_order_items, so I've created a file in [ModuleDir]/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items"  template="Vendor_Module::email/items.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and created my custom template in [ModuleDir]/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml
cleared cache and compiled, but nothing has changed.

Someone can help me?

Comment: I found that the best way to do this is through an event observer.
More details in the accepted answer here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159142/override-model-function-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in this code is adding a child block of `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items` without any name to `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items` block named "items". If you want to change the template of the "items" block the correct syntax is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::email/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```