# Override specific block in new order email

Tags: magento-2.1

How are we supposed to override the "Payment method" info block in a new order email?
Overriding this payment info block in the email seems to be more complicated than doing it in other places around M2.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Specify what you are trying to do? Means what purpose you want to overide this block?

Comment: During programmatic order creation, I add payment info for admin purposes  and I don't want that info to be displayed to frontend users. I have managed to override the block in many places successfully (order details, invoice...) but it's particularly difficult for the email, reason why I'm asking the question.

Comment: I'm trying to override the block from a custom module. it works everywhere but not in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to do this is through an event observer.
More details in the accepted answer here:
[Override model function Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159142/override-model-function-magento-2)